# CSS transform skewY

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Привет всем, верстаю макет из photoshop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видно по макету фононовая картинка стоит по горизонтали

решил использовать transform skewY 
как сделать что бы фоновая картинка не переворачивалась

вот мой код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.popular-position {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    transform: skewY(9deg);
    min-height: 600px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.popular-position > * {
    transform: skewY(-9deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="popular-position" style="background-image: url(img/bg_populars.jpg);">
 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="section_title">
   <h2><span>Популярные  </span> позиции </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x grid-margin-y">

  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Повернуть отдельно нативный фон нельзя - можно использовать "костыли" (задать фон псевдоэлементу и поворачивать его), но зачем? В чём вообще смысл Вашей задачи?